# How To get only open board in trello (not closed board)

Tags: show, trello

I want to show in my board page only open board in my trello

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                    url: allboardsurl,
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {id: id},
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("The request failed");
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your all data  come in Data then 
you can check the condition

if your result in ajax success

```
success: function (data) {
                        response = JSON.parse(data);
                         for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                                if (!response[i].closed) {
                               console.log(response[i].name);
                            }

                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, filter the data on the client, but it would be more efficient, to have only open boards returned. If you are using Trello provided client.js you can include filter in the query as follows:

```
Trello.get('/member/me/boards', { filter: "open"}, success, error);
```

If you build your URL by hand just add the filter in like here:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/member/me/boards?key=x&token=y&filter=open
```